# Copy all Powerpoint Picture Hyperlink to Excel (loop)

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, ms-office, powerpoint

I am trying to create a loop to go through each picture in my slideshow and paste each picture's corresponding hyperlink in an excel document as a list

I would also like the loop to loop through the pictures in order from left to right (ie in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dyVo.jpg) attached, select the upper left image (Target's ad), then the next image to the right (Rite-Aid's ad), then CVS's, then Walgreens', and then go to the next row which starts with Benadryl for Walgreens and repeat that process)
Here is the code I have thus far

```
'Code for getting hyperlinks of images in Powerpoint- and pasting into excel

Sub getLinks()

Dim pptSlide As Slide
Dim pptShape As Shape

Dim pptHLstring As String


Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Weekly Ad Recaps\Non-FSI\lookuptable Non FSI.xlsm")
i = 0

For Each pptSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
                i = i + 1
    If pptShape.Type = Shape Then
        On Error Resume Next
        xlWorkBook.Sheets("PPT H-Link Index").Range(Cells(i, 1)) = pptShape.Hyperlink.Address
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

Next pptShape
DoEvents
Next pptSlide

End Sub
```

The slideshow has a dozen slides all formatted the exact same way.
A macro to streamline this process would cut down on my weekly workload significantly

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!!

Comment: Are those images organized in a table?

Comment: no, each image is it's own separate entity. But each slide is formatted with 12 images in the exact same locations each week

Comment: Same locations AND same Z-Order perhaps?